# How to read a protobuf file partially, message by message in java?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I would like to read a large file with protobuf java.

Currently, I only manage to read the file in its entirety which is not practical as it is a large file.

whereas I do:

```
Ticks.parseFrom(inputStream)
```

or

```
Ticks.newBuilder().mergeFrom(inputStream)
```

the whole file and all the messages are loaded in memory.

`inputStream` here is an `InputStream` streaming a compressed file.

Is it possible to load them sequentially without using much memory?

Comment: you can read the file  [n * (message chunk size)]  ,lazy operation after marshalling the data if you dont want it all in the memory what are you planing to do with it?